# Prove that the $\sigma$-sets of the semiring $S$ form a topology for $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

> Prove that the $\sigma$-sets of the semiring $$S=\{[a,b): a,b, \in \mathbb R, a \le b \}$$ form a topology for the real numbers.

I know that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is a $\sigma$-set w.r.t. $S$ if there exists a disjoint sequence $\{ A_n\}$ of $S$ such that $\displaystyle A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

So in this case, I must show that if $\{[a_n, b_n): a_n,b_n \in \mathbb R, a_n\le b _n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of half-open intervals in $S$, then the set $\displaystyle A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{[a_n, b_n): a_n,b_n \in \mathbb R, a_n\le b _n\}$ forms a topology of $\mathbb R$.

How do I go about showing this though?

Comment: Note that the _family_ of such sets $A$ forms a topology, not just one set.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf . Thanks for pointing that out :). That makes sense :). I still don't know how to show that it forms a topology though. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The [*Sorgenfrey line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is $\Bbb R$ endowed with the topology generated by the base

$$\mathscr{B}=\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\}\;.$$

Since $\mathscr{B}$ is closed under finite intersections, this topology $\tau$ is just $\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}$. Clearly $\tau$ contains all of the $\sigma$-sets of $S$. To complete the argument, you need only show that if $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, then there is a countable $\mathscr{V}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\bigcup\mathscr{V}$. Let $A=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$.

- Let $U=\bigcup\{(a,b):[a,b)\in\mathscr{U}\}$; show that there is a countable $\mathscr{V}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $\bigcup\{(a,b):[a,b)\in\mathscr{V}_0\}=U$.
- Show that $A\setminus U$ is countable, so there is a countable $\mathscr{V}_1\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ that covers $A\setminus U$.

Now just let $\mathscr{V}=\mathscr{V}_0\cup\mathscr{V}_1$.